# Understanding proof that $f$ is a monomorphism if and only if injective

Tags: functions, solution-verification

I'm trying to understand the proof in Aluffi's book that $f: A \to B$ is injective if and only if it is a monomorphism. I've added some detail and reordered some things in his proof. How does this look?

> Suppose $f: A \to B$ is injective. If $A = \emptyset$, then the only functions $Z \to A$ is the empty function. Hence, $\alpha' = \alpha''$ vacuously. Suppose $A \neq \emptyset$. Then $f$ admits a left inverse $g: B \to A$, so $g \circ f = \mathrm{id}_A$. Given $\alpha', \alpha'': Z \to A$ with $f \circ \alpha' = f \circ \alpha''$, we have
> \begin{align*}
> \alpha' = \alpha \circ \mathrm{id}_A = \alpha' \circ \left(f \circ g\right) = \left(\alpha' \circ f\right) \circ g = \left(\alpha'' \circ f\right) \circ g = \alpha'' \circ \left(f \circ g\right) = \alpha'' \circ \mathrm{id}_A = \alpha'',
> \end{align*}
> so $f$ is a monomorphism, as desired. Conversely, suppose that $f$ is a monomorphism. If $A = \emptyset$, then $f: \emptyset \to B$ is vacuously injective, so suppose $A \neq \emptyset$. Take $Z = \{p\}$ for some element $p \in Z$, and suppose $f(a') = f(a'')$ for $a', a'' \in A$. Now, define $\alpha', \alpha'': Z \to A$ by $\alpha'(p) = a'$ and $\alpha''(p) = a''$. Then $f(\alpha'(p)) = f(\alpha''(p))$, i.e., $(f \circ \alpha')(p) = (f \circ \alpha'')(p)$. As $p$ is the only element of the domain $Z$, we have $f \circ \alpha' = f \circ \alpha''$. By the assumption that $f$ is a monomorphism, we deduce $\alpha' = \alpha''$, and hence $\alpha'(p) = \alpha''(p)$, i.e., $a' = a''$, so $f$ is injective, as desired.

Comment: The solution is fine, though the  fact that an injective function $f: A \to B$ has a left inverse if $A$ is nonempty is true but requires proof. One can make a simpler argument without using this fact, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is fine, but it does a lot of case analysis on whether sets are empty. This case analysis is unnecessary.

Fix a one-element set $1 = \{*\}$.

> $f$ is a monomorphism implies $f$ is injective.

Proof: Suppose $f : A \to B$ is a monomorphism. Consider $a, b \in A$. Suppose $f(a) = f(b)$. Define functions $g, h : 1 \to A$ by $g(*) = a$, $h(*) = b$. Then $f(g(*)) = f(h(*))$, so $f \circ g = f \circ h$ by function extensionality. Since $f$ is mono, we have $g = h$. Therefore, $a = g(*) = h(*) = b$.

> $f$ is injective implies $f$ is a monomorphism.

Proof: Suppose $f : A \to B$ is injective. Consider functions $g, h : C \to A$ such that $f \circ g = f \circ h$. We will use function extensionality to show that $g = h$. Consider an arbitrary $x \in C$. Then we have $f(g(x)) = f(h(x))$. Then since $f$ is injective, $g(x) = h(x)$. Therefore, $g = h$ by function extensionality.

This way, we don't require the law of excluded middle in our proof. This is very useful in situations where the law of excluded middle doesn't hold (for example, in the internal logic of toposes).

Comment: Thank you for this. The only thing I'm confused on, though, is that if $A$ is empty in your first proof, then I can't define a function $f,g: 1 \to A$, so don't I need to rule it out?

Comment: @BradG. For the "mono implies injective" proof, we are trying to prove the statement $\forall a \in A \forall b \in A (f(a) = f(b) \implies a = b)$. Whenever we seek to prove a statement of the form $\forall a \in A \forall b \in A (P(a, b))$, we can always suppose we are given some $a, b \in A$ and prove $P(a, b)$. There is no need to do any case analysis on whether $A$ is empty. It's just applying the rules of logic.

Comment: It makes sense to me that the implication is vacuous if $A$ is empty, but if in the process of proving that, are we allowed to define a function $g,h$ that may not exist? That's my big confusion.

Comment: At the stage in the proof you are worried about, we have already hypothesised that there are $a,b \in A$, so defining then $g,h$ then is unproblematic.  To prove a statement of the form $\forall a \in A \forall b \in A: Q(a,b)$ it is valid reasoning to assume for arbitrary $a,b \in A$ and then show that $Q(a,b)$ must hold (regardless of weather $A$ is *actually* empty. Such forms of reasoning can be formalised in various  'natural deduction' proof systems, which is a keyword you can search for to learn more about these types of argument.

Comment: @BradG. user26828206 has a good explanation. When we define $g$, we have already assumed that $a \in A$. So defining $g(*) = a$ is a perfectly valid definition of a function, and we know it's valid based on the assumption we made that $a \in A$. Similarly for the definition of $h$.